# Bootstrap tabs not working in Vue app

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am creating an app with vue, vue-router and bootstrap. I am trying to implement tags in bootstrap, like following:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">buzz</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#references" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">references</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">bbb</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="references">ccc</div>
</div>
```

This code work without an issue without Vuejs: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4o11vj9/)

But when I use this same code with Vue and Vue router, It stops working, I am not getting any error either.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
    { name: 'Tabs', path: '/', component: Tabs }
  ]
})
new Vue({ el: '#app', store, router })
```

Complete fiddle with not working tabs [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Ld9bLw/).

What I have figured is, if I remove `mode history` from the router it starts to work, but that I can not do.

```
mode: 'history',
```

Why this is happening and how can this be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your example it is due to vue-router not matching the path `/` so never serving the tabs:

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebigsurf/u8Ld9bLw/1/)

If the issue is coming in as jQuery is pushing a hash URI then you will likely need to add a wildcard to your routes `path` to match this new URI, i.e.

**http://example.com/tabs-path#3**

route:

```
{ name: 'Tabs', path: '/tabs-path*', component: Tabs }
```

Comment: From where this `_display` came?

Comment: it's just the jsfiddle uri - in your app you'd change it to where it needs to point. Basically check the `$route.path` is pointing where you think it is as if not the component won't be rendered

Comment: ok, I am using these tabs in my code also but there also it is not working. It appends the tag in the url, like http:myUrl/path#tag3, but content does not changes, any cue why it might be happening?

Comment: I imagine it's to do with the hash var in the URI. Have you tried adding a wildcard for the tags, something like: `http://example.com/tabs-path#3` = `{ name: 'Tabs', path: '/tabs-path#*', component: Tabs }` note the asterix at the end of the URI. check out: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#advanced-matching-patterns for more info

Comment: This stops the rendering of the router view in my local.

Comment: sorry yeah - you'd need to play with the matching as I guess when it first loads it wouldn't have the `#`, I'll have a quick look

Comment: I will close this here, as you don't have all the context, I will try to reproduce it in fiddle or somewhere else, thanks for help. Let me know if you come across something related.